# How can I make super the target of an NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I'm trying to use a `NSTimer` to call a function in an class's superclass.

The function works if I call it like this:

```
[super playNarrationForPage:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

But if I do this:

```
NSTimer *narrationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.5
                                                           target:self.superclass
                                                           selector:@selector(playNarrationForPage:) 
                                                           userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
                                                           repeats:NO
                          ];
```

I get this error: `unrecognized selector sent to class 0x106890
2012-07-06 21:14:59.522 MyApp[19955:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[MyBaseClass playNarrationForPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x106890'`

I've tried setting `super` as the `target:` but I'm told "Use of undeclared identifier super". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `self.superclass` returns a `Class` object, it's definitely not what you want.

Also, you don't seem to understand how an `NSTimer` calls its target.  You're using an `NSNumber` as the timer's `userInfo`, and your `playNarrationForPage:` method seems to expect an `NSNumber` argument.  But an `NSTimer` does **not** pass its `userInfo` as the argument when it calls its target!  The `NSTimer` passes *itself* as the argument, like this:

```
// self is the NSTimer object here!
[self.target performSelector:self.selector withObject:self];
```

You **must** create a new method for your timer to call.  This new method needs to take the timer as its argument, like this:

```
- (void)narrationTimerDidFire:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self playNarrationForPage:timer.userInfo];
}
```

Then you need to use that selector when you create your timer:

```
NSTimer *narrationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.5
    target:self
    selector:@selector(narrationTimerDidFire:)
    userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
    repeats:NO];
```

If you really want to make `narrationTimerDidFire:` call `[super playNarrationForPage:]`, the compiler will let you.  But doing that is **very fishy**.  If you haven't overridden `playNarrationForPage:` in your subclass, then there's no reason to refer to `super` directly; your subclass inherits its superclass's `playNarrationForPage:` method.  If you *have* overridden `playNarrationForPage:` in your subclass, then bypassing it from your timer's callback indicates that something is wrong with your design.

Answer (score 5):

The *only* time you should use `super` is when you are in a method and want to call the superclass's implementation **of the same method** (including indirectly -- see below).

`self.superclass` doesn't make sense as the target of the timer *unless* your goal is to call a class method on the superclass.

Just use `self` as the target.    If that won't work because you are overriding `playNarrationForPage:` and want to delay the invocation to super, then create a separate method that does something like:

```
- (void) _delayedDoIt
{
     [super playNarrationForPage:1];
}
```

And call that from self's implementation of `playNarrationForPage:` via the timer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly tell it to call the `super` method. `target` is only a pointer to an object, `super` does not have a separate pointer address from your `self` instance.

Also by assigning the `target` to `self.superclass` you are telling the `target` to be the class. Therefore your trying call a class method rather than an instance method which is not what you want to do.

The only way to do this would be to assign target to `self` and have a separate method such as:

```
- (void)callSuperMethod
{
    [super playNarrationForPage:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
}
```